# JavaScript : passing javascript arrayof object to external javascript

Tags: javascript

in my page1.html i have a an array of

```
var responder = {
     "id" : [],
     "name" : []
};
details(responder);
```

responder contains id = 1, name = "josh"

and i want to get the responder data in a external js "pop-up.js"

```
<script>
   details(responder){
      for (var i = 0; i < responder.length; i++){
        alert(responder['id']);
       }
 }
```

but the result is undefined or sometimes NaN

how can i pass correctly the data of responder?

Comment: by ensuring that page1.html script is positioned above the script tag (which import) pop-up.js

Comment: check your code first... full errors are there...
differetiate array and object then write the function syntax properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that in page1.html, you have a script tag

```
<script>
var responder = {
     "id" : [],
     "name" : []
};
details(responder);
</script>
```

If the `script` tag to import `pop-up.js` is placed above this one then it will not have access to `responder`.

Another way to do it would be if you use window.onload (or document.onload) event in pop.js, so that your DOM is ready (i.e. all scripts has been loaded)

```
   window.onload = function(){
      function details(responder){
         for (var key in responder ){
           alert(responder[key ]);
          }
       }   
   };
```